# Appending To A Json Object Using Python

Tags: python, json, object

I want to append to this json object.
JSON Before Appending:

```
{
  "Profiles": [
  ]
}
```

I want to add this info:

```
    {
      "Profile": "1",
      "First": "1",
      "Last": "1",
      "Credit Card": "",
      "Exp Month": "1",
      "Exp Year": "1",
      "Cvv Code": "1",
      "Home Address": "1",
      "Zip Code": "1",
      "State": "1"
    }
```

I tried doing this:

```
            #Profile Data
            data['Profiles'].append({
                'Profile': profile_name,
                'First': first,
                'Last': last,
                'Credit Card': cc,
                'Exp Month': exp_month,
                'Exp Year': exp_year,
                'Cvv Code': cvv,
                'Home Address': addr,
                'Zip Code': zip_code,
                'State': state
            })
```

Instead of just adding that info, it repeats what's already in the json file and then adds the info outside of it.
This is the result of the above:

```
{
  "Profiles": [
  ]
}{
  "Profiles": [
    {
      "Profile": "1",
      "First": "1",
      "Last": "1",
      "Credit Card": "1",
      "Exp Month": "1",
      "Exp Year": "1",
      "Cvv Code": "",
      "Home Address": "1",
      "Zip Code": "1",
      "State": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Essentially what I'm trying to accomplish is adding a whole bunch of profiles to a json object (Profiles).

Comment: I have no idea how you achieved such as output with python script, it's really hard to do accidentally.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Can it be because the mode I opened the file with was read/write 'r+'?

Comment: Ahhh, yes, that's the reason. You should rewrite file not append, use `'w+'`.

Comment: @OlvinRoght So everything else keep the same just change the mode?

Comment: Just try, if it helped - great.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should first load in your json data in python using this function:

```py
import json
data = json.load(json_file)
```

Then you can use your append method. After that you can use `json.dumps()` function to convert back to json string.

More info here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/append-to-json-file-using-python/.